# No more mulligan?

Tags: ios, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

In Magic 2013, you have the option before a duel to mulligan, or to ditch your hand and draw a new set of 7 cards, and then 1 less card for each mulligan thereafter. However, after playing with the free version of Magic 2014 for iOS, I have yet to encounter this option. I do seem to notice that my draw always seems to have at least 2 lands and no more than 4, but that just might be due to the small sample count.

Is mulligan gone for 2014? Or does this functionality get "unlocked" when I purchase the complete version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as with `MTG Duels of Planeswalker 2013` and `2012`(if I remember correctly), you can only mulligan if you have the full version of the game, this option doesn't exist in a free version.